# Bash choose between two values but choose one value 4 times more than another

Tags: bash

It's simple to call a number between two numbers

```
echo $( shuf -i 15-16 -n 1 )
```

or call two numbers using variables

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=15
var2=16
echo "${var1}${var2}"
exit ;
    sh
```

Question - is it possible to call number 15 (or $var1 from second example) - 4 times more often than number 16 (or $var2 from second example) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask `shuf` for a single value and provide it with input data that contains four times as many `15` than `16`.  In `bash`,

```
shuf -n 1 <<<$'15\n15\n15\n15\n16'
```